# Kubernetes reports "pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)" even though it would?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I don't understand why I'm receiving this error. A new node should definitely be able to accommodate the pod. As I'm only requesting **768Mi** of memory and **450m** of CPU, and the instance group that would be autoscaled is of type `n1-highcpu-2` - **2 vCPU, 1.8GB**.

How could I diagnose this further?

**kubectl describe pod:**

```
Name:           initial-projectinitialabcrad-697b74b449-848bl
Namespace:      production
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=initial-projectinitialabcrad
                appType=abcrad-api
                pod-template-hash=2536306005
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:             
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/initial-projectinitialabcrad-697b74b449
Containers:
  app:
    Image:      gcr.io/example-project-abcsub/projectinitial-abcrad-app:production_6b0b3ddabc68d031e9f7874a6ea49ee9902207bc
    Port:       <none>
    Host Port:  <none>
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:     250m
      memory:  512Mi
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-srv8k (ro)
  nginx:
    Image:      gcr.io/example-project-abcsub/projectinitial-abcrad-nginx:production_6b0b3ddabc68d031e9f7874a6ea49ee9902207bc
    Port:       80/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     128Mi
    Readiness:    http-get http://:80/api/v1/ping delay=5s timeout=10s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-srv8k (ro)
  cloudsql-proxy:
    Image:      gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.11
    Port:       3306/TCP
    Host Port:  0/TCP
    Command:
      /cloud_sql_proxy
      -instances=example-project-abcsub:us-central1:abcfn-staging=tcp:0.0.0.0:3306
      -credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json
    Limits:
      cpu:     1
      memory:  1Gi
    Requests:
      cpu:        100m
      memory:     128Mi
    Mounts:
      /secrets/cloudsql from cloudsql-instance-credentials (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-srv8k (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False 
Volumes:
  cloudsql-instance-credentials:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  cloudsql-instance-credentials
    Optional:    false
  default-token-srv8k:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-srv8k
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason             Age                  From                Message
  ----     ------             ----                 ----                -------
  Normal   NotTriggerScaleUp  4m (x29706 over 3d)  cluster-autoscaler  pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)
  Warning  FailedScheduling   4m (x18965 over 3d)  default-scheduler   0/4 nodes are available: 3 Insufficient memory, 4 Insufficient cpu.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the hardware requests (confusingly the error message made me assume this)  but it's due to my pod affinity rule defined:

```
podAffinity:
  requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
  - labelSelector:
      matchExpressions:
      - key: appType
        operator: NotIn
        values:
        - example-api
    topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
```

Comment: That should still triger the autoscale or am I wrong? If the cluster autoscaler would add a new node, the pod would fit on it.

Comment: So basically you needed to change the `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` to `preferredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution`?

Comment: No, I think it was due to the fact that a new node wouldn't be "compatible" with the pod due to the podAfffinity defined.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using K8s from a cloud provider like GKE/EKS, maybe it is worth taking a look at the cloud provider resource quota!

Even everything looks reasonable, K8s gave the same error "pod didn't trigger scale-up"! And that was because the CPU quota was exhausted! (K8s has nothing to do with that limitation, so the error is not clear from K8s side).

Answer (score 0):

Running on AWS EKS, I received the same message when the Auto Scaling Group that was configured for the pods (with a taint and toleration) reached the maximum capacity. Enlarging the max capacity caused new nodes to be created and the pods to start running.