# Kubernetes autoscaler - NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, amazon-eks

I'd like to run a 'job' per node, one pod on a node at a time.

- I've scheduled a bunch of jobs
- I have a whole bunch of pending pods now
- I'd like these pending pods to now trigger a node scaling up event (which does **NOT** happen)

---

Very much like this issue (made by myself): [Kubernetes reports "pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added)" even though it would?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54314246/kubernetes-reports-pod-didnt-trigger-scale-up-it-wouldnt-fit-if-a-new-node-i)

However in this case it should indeed fit on a new node.

How can I diagnose why Kubernetes has determined that a node scaling event is not possible?

My job yaml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: example-job-${job_id}
  labels:
    job-in-progress: job-in-progress-yes
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: example-job-${job_id}
    spec:
      # this bit ensures a job/container does not get scheduled along side another - 'anti' affinity
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname 
            labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: job-in-progress
                operator: NotIn
                values:
                - job-in-progress-yes
      containers:
      - name: buster-slim
        image: debian:buster-slim
        command: ["bash"]
        args: ["-c", "sleep 60; echo ${echo_param}"]
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Autoscaler logs:

```
I0920 19:27:58.190751       1 static_autoscaler.go:128] Starting main loop
I0920 19:27:58.261972       1 auto_scaling_groups.go:320] Regenerating instance to ASG map for ASGs: []
I0920 19:27:58.262003       1 aws_manager.go:152] Refreshed ASG list, next refresh after 2019-09-20 19:28:08.261998185 +0000 UTC m=+302.102284346
I0920 19:27:58.262092       1 static_autoscaler.go:261] Filtering out schedulables
I0920 19:27:58.264212       1 static_autoscaler.go:271] No schedulable pods
I0920 19:27:58.264246       1 scale_up.go:262] Pod default/example-job-21-npv6p is unschedulable
I0920 19:27:58.264252       1 scale_up.go:262] Pod default/example-job-28-zg4f8 is unschedulable
I0920 19:27:58.264258       1 scale_up.go:262] Pod default/example-job-24-fx9rd is unschedulable
I0920 19:27:58.264263       1 scale_up.go:262] Pod default/example-job-6-7mvqs is unschedulable
I0920 19:27:58.264268       1 scale_up.go:262] Pod default/example-job-20-splpq is unschedulable
I0920 19:27:58.264273       1 scale_up.go:262] Pod default/example-job-25-g5mdg is unschedulable
I0920 19:27:58.264279       1 scale_up.go:262] Pod default/example-job-16-wtnw4 is unschedulable
I0920 19:27:58.264284       1 scale_up.go:262] Pod default/example-job-7-g89cp is unschedulable
I0920 19:27:58.264289       1 scale_up.go:262] Pod default/example-job-8-mglhh is unschedulable
I0920 19:27:58.264323       1 scale_up.go:304] Upcoming 0 nodes
I0920 19:27:58.264370       1 scale_up.go:420] No expansion options
I0920 19:27:58.264511       1 static_autoscaler.go:333] Calculating unneeded nodes
I0920 19:27:58.264533       1 utils.go:474] Skipping ip-10-0-1-118.us-west-2.compute.internal - no node group config
I0920 19:27:58.264542       1 utils.go:474] Skipping ip-10-0-0-65.us-west-2.compute.internal - no node group config
I0920 19:27:58.265063       1 factory.go:33] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"example-job-25-g5mdg", UID:"d2e0e48c-dbd9-11e9-a9e2-024e7db9d360", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"7256", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 
I0920 19:27:58.265090       1 factory.go:33] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"example-job-8-mglhh", UID:"c7d3ce78-dbd9-11e9-a9e2-024e7db9d360", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"7267", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 
I0920 19:27:58.265101       1 factory.go:33] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"example-job-6-7mvqs", UID:"c6a5b0e4-dbd9-11e9-a9e2-024e7db9d360", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"7273", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 
I0920 19:27:58.265110       1 factory.go:33] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"example-job-20-splpq", UID:"cfeb9521-dbd9-11e9-a9e2-024e7db9d360", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"7259", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 
I0920 19:27:58.265363       1 factory.go:33] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"example-job-21-npv6p", UID:"d084c067-dbd9-11e9-a9e2-024e7db9d360", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"7275", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 
I0920 19:27:58.265384       1 factory.go:33] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"example-job-16-wtnw4", UID:"ccbe48e0-dbd9-11e9-a9e2-024e7db9d360", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"7265", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 
I0920 19:27:58.265490       1 factory.go:33] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"example-job-28-zg4f8", UID:"d4afc868-dbd9-11e9-a9e2-024e7db9d360", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"7269", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 
I0920 19:27:58.265515       1 factory.go:33] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"example-job-24-fx9rd", UID:"d24975e5-dbd9-11e9-a9e2-024e7db9d360", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"7271", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added): 
I0920 19:27:58.265685       1 static_autoscaler.go:360] Scale down status: unneededOnly=true lastScaleUpTime=2019-09-20 19:23:23.822104264 +0000 UTC m=+17.662390361 lastScaleDownDeleteTime=2019-09-20 19:23:23.822105556 +0000 UTC m=+17.662391653 lastScaleDownFailTime=2019-09-20 19:23:23.822106849 +0000 UTC m=+17.662392943 scaleDownForbidden=false isDeleteInProgress=false
I0920 19:27:58.265910       1 factory.go:33] Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:"Pod", Namespace:"default", Name:"example-job-7-g89cp", UID:"c73cfaea-dbd9-11e9-a9e2-024e7db9d360", APIVersion:"v1", ResourceVersion:"7263", FieldPath:""}): type: 'Normal' reason: 'NotTriggerScaleUp' pod didn't trigger scale-up (it wouldn't fit if a new node is added):
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the wrong parameters defined on the autoscaler.

I had to modify the `node-group-auto-discovery` and `nodes` parameters.

```
        - ./cluster-autoscaler
        - --cloud-provider=aws
        - --namespace=default
        - --scan-interval=25s
        - --scale-down-unneeded-time=30s
        - --nodes=1:20:terraform-eks-demo20190922161659090500000007--terraform-eks-demo20190922161700651000000008
        - --node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled,k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/example-job-runner
        - --logtostderr=true
        - --stderrthreshold=info
        - --v=4
```

When installing the cluster autoscaler it is not enough to simply apply the example config, e.g.:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/examples/cluster-autoscaler-autodiscover.yaml
```

As documented in [the user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/cluster-autoscaler.html), that config has placeholder for your eks cluster name in the value for `node-group-auto-discovery`, and you must either replace it before applying, or update it after deploying.

Comment: it's not recommend to set both `nodes` and `node-group-auto-discovery`. usually `node-group-auto-discovery` will be enough
https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/README.md#auto-discovery-setup

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this as well.  I didn't see this super well documented where you think it would be.  Here is the detailed explanation on the main [README.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/57e54f6b93b170ec3d0674300441738274627aa4/charts/cluster-autoscaler-chart#aws---using-auto-discovery-of-tagged-instance-groups)

> #### AWS - Using auto-discovery of tagged instance groups
>
> Auto-discovery finds ASGs tags as below and automatically manages them
> based on the min and max size specified in the ASG.
> `cloudProvider=aws` only.
>
> - Tag the ASGs with keys to match `.Values.autoDiscovery.tags`, by default: `k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled` and
>   `k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/<YOUR CLUSTER NAME>`
> - Verify the [IAM Permissions](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/57e54f6b93b170ec3d0674300441738274627aa4/charts/cluster-autoscaler-chart/README.md#aws---iam)
> - Set `autoDiscovery.clusterName=<YOUR CLUSTER NAME>`
> - Set `awsRegion=<YOUR AWS REGION>`
> - Set `awsAccessKeyID=<YOUR AWS KEY ID>` and `awsSecretAccessKey=<YOUR AWS SECRET KEY>` if you want to [use AWS credentials directly instead
>   of an instance
>   role](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/README.md#using-aws-credentials)
>
> `$ helm install my-release autoscaler/cluster-autoscaler-chart --set autoDiscovery.clusterName=<CLUSTER NAME>`

My issue was that I did not specify both tags instead only specifying the `k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled` tag.  This makes sense now that I think about it as if you have multiple k8s clusters in the same account the cluster-autoscaler will need to know which ASG to actually scale.

Answer (score 2):

I mistakenly added these as node labels `k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled` and `k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/<YOUR CLUSTER NAME>`

But they should actually be tags on the nodes in the worker groups.

Specifically, if you're using the AWS EKS module in Terraform -

```
  workers_group_defaults = {
    tags = [{
        key                 = "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled"
        value               = "TRUE"
        propagate_at_launch = true
      },{
        key                 = "k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/${var.cluster_name}"
        value               = "owned"
        propagate_at_launch = true
      }]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solve this issue in Google Cloud Platform (GCP) simply increase the `maximum number of nodes`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have applied raw autoscaler from eksctl workshop. In order to fix, I went to autoscaler deployment and changed k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/eksctl-workshop to k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/<YOUR_CLUSTER_RNAME>

```
- ./cluster-autoscaler
- --v=4
- --stderrthreshold=info
- --cloud-provider=aws
- --skip-nodes-with-local-storage=false
- --expander=least-waste
- --node-group-auto-discovery=asg:tag=k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/enabled,k8s.io/cluster-autoscaler/<YOUR_CLUSTER_RNAME>
- --balance-similar-node-groups
- --skip-nodes-with-system-pods=false
```